# What does a JEDIS multi transaction exec returning null or empty request mean?

Tags: redis, jedis

I am doing:

```
Transaction t = jedis.multi();
t.incr(key);
List<Object> response = t.exec();
```

This works well, but maybe 10 times a week the response is either null or it's an empty list. I read that this happens if the connection is closed, but no exception is being thrown. Is this null/empty response a "valid" response and what does it mean?

Comment: Neither null not empty is valid response. You can create an issue here https://github.com/redis/jedis/issues

Comment: @sazzad Do you happen to know if this code (with only one command between the multi and exec) producing a List<Object> that has multiple elements would be just as invalid, or if that would represent something else?

Comment: That would be invalid as well.